# euclidean algorithm and linear combination for gcd

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

(i) Use the Euclidean Algorithm to find gcd(1253, 7930).

(ii) Using the workings in (i), find m, n ∈ Z such that
gcd(1253, 7930) = 1253m + 7930n.

i) 
7930 = 1253*6 + 412

1253 = 412*3 + 17

412 = 17*24 + 4

17 = 4*4 + 1

4 = 1*4 + 0

So gcd = 1.

ii)1 = 1*17 + -4(4)

4 = 1*(412) + -24*(17)

17 = 1*(1253) + -3*(412)

412 = 1*(7930) + -6*(1253)

So 1 = 1*(17) + -4*(4)

= 1*(17) + -4((1*(412) + -24*(17)))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3nJV.jpg)

I'm up to ii) but I got confused. I tried following an example online but I got lost and idk if I'm on the right track or where to go from here?
where I have the 412 in the last line I wrote, would I substitute in the 1 * 7930 + -6*1253 thing?
and in the 17 part in the last line I'd substitute in 11253 + - 3412?
what would I do from there to find m and n?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There exists an *extended Euclidean algorithm* which makes all these computations  automatic, without having to calculate backwards.

Comment: It is usually simpler and far less error prone to compute the Bezout identity in the *forward* direction by using [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3181308/2422) of the Extended Euclidean algorithm, which keeps track of each remainder's expression as a linear combination of the gcd arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

That is, given $n,m$ follow the dollowing algorithm
$$
\eqalign{
  & r_{\, - 2}  = n = 1\,n + 0\,m  \cr 
  & r_{\, - 1}  = m = 0\,n + 1\,m  \cr 
  & r_{\,0}  = r_{\, - 2}  - \left\lfloor {{{r_{\, - 2} } \over {r_{\, - 1} }}} \right\rfloor r_{\, - 1}  = \bmod \left( {r_{\, - 2} ,\;r_{\, - 1} } \right) = \bmod \left( {n,\;m} \right) = k_{\,0} \,n + l_{\,0} \,m  \cr 
  & r_{\,1}  = \bmod \left( {r_{\, - 1} ,\;r_{\, - 0} } \right) = k_{\,1} \,n + l_{\,1} \,m  \cr 
  &  \vdots   \cr 
  & r_{\,j} \quad \left| {\;0 \le j} \right.\quad  = \bmod \left( {r_{\,j - 2} ,\;r_{\,j - 1} } \right) = k_{\,j} \,n + l_{\,j} \,m  \cr 
  &  \vdots   \cr 
  & r_{\,h - 1}  = \gcd (m,n) = \bmod \left( {r_{\,h - 3} ,\;r_{\,h - 2} } \right) = k_{\,\,h - 1} \,n + l_{\,h - 1} \,m = n'\,n + m'\,m  \cr 
  & r_{\,h}  = 0 = \bmod \left( {r_{\,h - 2} ,\;r_{\,h - 1} } \right) = k_{\,\,h} \,n + l_{\,h} \,m = \left( { - m^ *  } \right)n + n^ *  \,m = m^ *  \,n + \left( { - n^ *  } \right)m \cr} 
$$

At the last but one step you get $r_{h-1}= \gcd(m,n)= n' n + m'm$

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  You started out with 1 as a linear combination of 17 and 4, and then a combination of 412 and 17 (although you could stand to make it prettier :).  Next you have to make it a combination of 1253 and 412 and finally a combination of 7930 and 1253.

Like this:

```
1   =   17-4(4)
    =   17-4(412-24(17))
    =   17-4(412)+96(17)
    =   97(17)-4(412)
    =   97(1253-3(412))-4(412)
    =   97(1253)-291(412)-4(412)
    =   97(1253)-295(412)
    =   97(1253)-295(7930-6(1253))
    =   97(1253)-295(7930)+1770(1253)
    =   1867(1253)-295(7930)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard layout of the *extended Euclidean algorithm*: $u_i$ and $v_i$ denote the coefficients of a Bézout's relation: $\;r_i=1253 u_i +7930v_i$ for the  remainder at the $i$-th step of the Euclidean algorithm and $q_i$ is the corresponding quotient:
\begin{array}{rrrrl}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i \\\hline
7930 &  0    &    1 \\
1253 &  1    &    0 & 6 \\\hline
 412 &  -6   &    1 & 3 \\
  17 &  19   &   -3 & 24 \\
   4 & -462  & -73 & 4 \\
\color{red}1 & \color{red}{1867} &  \color{red}{-295} \\ \hline
\end{array}